# How to unlink/remove files and images from s3 bucket using nmp papercut?

Tags: node.js, express

Can anyone please tell me how do I remove/erase/unlink images/files from amazon s3 storage using npm papercut 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/papercut

I have successfully uploaded images/files by using following code:

```
var papercut = require('papercut');
  papercut.configure('production', function(){
  papercut.set('storage', 's3')
  papercut.set('S3_KEY', process.env.S3_KEY)
  papercut.set('S3_SECRET', process.env.S3_SECRET)
  papercut.set('bucket', 'papercut')
});
AvatarUploader = papercut.Schema(function(schema){
  schema.version({
    name: 'avatar',
    size: '200x200',
    process: 'crop'
  });

  schema.version({
    name: 'small',
    size: '50x50',
    process: 'crop'
  });
});

uploader = new AvatarUploader();

uploader.process('image1', file.path, function(images){
  console.log(images.avatar); // '/images/uploads/image1-avatar.jpg'
  console.log(images.small); // '/images/uploads/image1-small.jpg'
})
```

but unable to unlink/erase images again at the time of delete user profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to knox module, then

```
var knox = require('knox'); 
var client = knox.createClient({
    key: S3_KEY,
    secret: S3_SECRET,
    bucket: BUCKET_NAME
});
client.deleteFile(imgPath, function(err, res){
    console.log('Clip delete err :',err,', Clip path :',imgPath);
});

imgPath = s3 image url.
```

There you go...